# Warning Message While Plotting a Piecewise Function in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to plot this function in R

```
f <- function(a,b,c,x){
 if(a<=x){
   return(c*x)} 
 if(x<=b){
   return(-c*x)}
 return(0)}
```

but when I try to plot it with:

```
a<-0
b<-6
c<-3
curve(f(a,b,c,x), xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,3), col='blue', lwd=3, add=FALSE)
```

I get:

```
Warning message in if (a <= x) {:
“the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used”
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `f` can't operate with vectors for `x` since the condition `(a <= x)` isn't straight forward to evaluate for a vector.

Let's take a look at

```r
x <- -6:6
f(a,b,c,x)
```

Your function `f` doesn't understand what to do with `x` while evaluating

```
if (a <= x) { code }
```

so the first element of `x` is always used.

So, what to do?

```
x   <- -6:6
f_2 <- function(x) { sapply(x, function(x) f(a,b,c,x)) }

curve(f_2, xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(0,20), col="blue", lwd=2, add=FALSE)
```

We define a new function `f_2`. `sapply` takes one element of `x` and uses it with `f(a,b,c,x)` than uses the next element etc. This function works with vectors `x` as input.

Compare it to

```r
curve(f(a,b,c,x), xlim=c(-6,6), ylim=c(0,20), col="blue", lwd=2, add=FALSE)
```

for better understanding.